# How do I close a React Native Modal?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am currently running into an issue where I can open my react-native modal just fine but once it's open I can't seem to close it. I just started using react-native about three weeks ago so I am extremely new to this.

I have tried implementing solutions that I've found online but nothing seemed to work for me. The opening functionality is great and seems to be working perfectly but when it comes to closing the modal none of the things I've tried have seemed to give the modal that ability. I have not been able to find a solid solution for my exact problem anywhere!

This is how I am opening the modal.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   refreshing: false,
    display: false
  };
}

triggerModal() {
 this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    display: true
   }
  });
}

<View>
  <Button onPress = { () => this.triggerModal() } title = "Open Modal"></Button>

  <DisplayModal display = { this.state.display } />
</View>
```

This is the modal itself, I am trying to use a button to close it.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Modal, View, Image, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

const DisplayModal = (props) => (
  <Modal visible={ props.display } animationType = "slide" 
onRequestClose={ this.display }>
<View>
  <Button title="close" onPress = { () => !props.display }></Button>
</View>
</Modal>
)

export default DisplayModal;
```

As my familiarity with react-native is limited, it has been difficult wrapping my head around how some aspects of the framework function... I'm probably just making a dumb mistake somewhere in the code.

I appreciate any help with this problem!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've almost got it, however we can make a few tweaks to get it working as you want.

As your `DisplayModal` has no state of its own, the state must be controlled by its parent component. So with that in mind we can do the following. Firstly pass an additional prop called `closeDisplay` to the `DisplayModal`. We're going to pass a function that sets the `display` property in `state` to `false`.

```
<DisplayModal 
  display={this.state.display} 
  closeDisplay={() => this.setState({display: false})} // <- we are passing this function
/>
```

Then in our `DisplayModal` component we are going to call that function to close the modal.  So your `DisplayModal` component should look like this:

```
const DisplayModal = (props) => (
  <Modal 
    visible={ props.display } 
    animationType = "slide" 
    onRequestClose={ this.display }>
    <View>
      <Button 
       title="close" 
       onPress = { () => props.closeDisplay() }> // <- here we call the function that we passed
    </Button>
    </View>
  </Modal>
)
```

Notice that the `onPress` function of the `Button` in the `DisplayModal` component, we are calling the function `closeDisplay()`. This function then sets the state in the parent component, which in turn gets passed back down to the `DisplayModal` component causing it to hide.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much for taking the time and explaining the solution step by step. Definitely gave me a better overview on how things are supposed to work. I appreciate it Andrew!

Comment: You're welcome, we all start somewhere. I find the one line answers terrible as it does nothing for those looking for help. A little explanation goes a long way. But what makes it even better is that you took the time to write a good question. You showed what you had done, and were clear about what you want to accomplish. Keep up the good work and with persistence you will get there :)

Comment: I could not agree with you more. I can't stand when someone writes up a quick example of how they got something to work without fully explaining how each individual aspect of the example works... Thanks again! Really appreciate the help and the kind words. I'll definitely keep going at it because I've enjoyed it so far!